# sqlite3_step returns SQLITE_CONSTRAINT

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, indexing

I have a local SQLite3 Database in my iOS application.

Usually everything works as needed, but sometimes I receive a strange error (`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`) when I try to `insert` a new record to my table, calling `sqlite3_step(statement)` method. This happens after the table is dropped and recreated one more time.(Yes, I need to drop the table and recreate, not just delete all records in my case).

---

Here is how I create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
reference text PRIMARY KEY not null collate nocase, 
value text not null collate nocase)
```

My table doesn't have any created manual indexes, just automatically generated unique index `"sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1"`. As I read [here(lang_creatable)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) it is a normal case.

---

Here is some code:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlString UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
if (result == SQLITE_OK) {

   int sql_result = sqlite3_step(statement);
   // here is receive sql_result == SQLITE_CONSTRAINT (19)
}
```

---

The problem  is not surely in sql query string. As I also read, I can received this error when I try to insert some record with the same primary key as already exists. In my case I have an empty table and receive this error.

So the question is what can cause the reason of getting `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT` error? Can unique index not to be deleted after dropping the table and still contain some information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the error message returned by `sqlite3_errmsg` and it will tell you precisely which constraint is failing and why the insert is failing. It will probably report either

- "column reference is not unique" - you get this when the `reference` value you're trying to insert already exists in the table; or
- "value may not be NULL" - you get this when you try to insert `NULL` into a column defined as `NOT NULL`.

Both of those errors would return in a return code of `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`. Only by looking at `sqlite3_errmsg` can you efficiently diagnose the source of the problem.

Frankly, I'm assuming that the former is the issue (the `reference` you're inserting already exists in the table), but until you look at the `sqlite3_errmsg`, we're just guessing.

```
int result;

if ((result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_prepare error: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), result);
}

if ((result = sqlite3_step(statement)) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"%s: step error: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), result);
}
else
    NSLog(@"success");

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Look at the `sqlite3_errmsg` and it will tell you precisely what went wrong. You might then want to examine the values you're trying to insert and compare that to the values already in the table as well as against the constraints you've defined (`NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thank you for answer, i've tested adding sqlite3_errormsg. As a result it shows me **step error: column reference is not unique (19)**. But as I asked in a question, how can it be possible to receive this error message when I have an empty table?

Comment: @George This means your table is *not* empty.

Comment: May be it sounds funny, but it is empty. As I told in my question. First I drop the table, than I create it. After these 2 actions I try to insert some record and receive an error, also I look at the SQLite Manager and see that the table is dropped, debugging step by step, and see that it is empty

Comment: @George It's hard to say without seeing code. In the absence of code, we'll all naturally suspect some simple logic error (e.g. opening database from bundle, not checking for `SQLITE_OK` response from the `DROP` command, etc.) that prevented the records from actually being deleted like you think they are. If worst comes to worst, perhaps you should do a `REINDEX` of the table or `PRAGMA integrity_check` of the entire database.

Comment: I still can't find the reason of the problem, **but** it solves if I reconnect to database after recreating the table. So I make sqlite3_close than sqlite3_open and after that I do not receive any errors. I think may be there exists something like cache in the SQLite connection, which is not correctly updated. So I close the question. Thank you.

Comment: @George You might see that behavior if you have a `BEGIN` without a `END`/`COMMIT` (though I was unable to reproduce this specific behavior). Regardless, it's great that you found a work around. You could also try doing `DELETE FROM MyTable` rather than dropping and recreating.

Comment: Or try wrapping your `DROP` and `CREATE` with a `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: There are no transations no, so the problem is not some transaction intersections, but it is nice solution to add a transaction. I will try, thank you.

Comment: @George I'd also check to make sure you call `sqlite3_finalize` for ever statement you prepare. Failure to finalize could result in data being cached (and cause leaks).